# Staghorn fern back turning black

Tags: diseases, fungus, ferns

I have not been overwatering my staghorn fern, I water them at the base about 60cc every week.

I don't most my plants very often and they have been stable for a year until this happened. The only thing is that my place is warmer this summer because the AC is temporarily broken.

I have made sure to let dry before watering but the problem is just getting worse. I suspect it might be a fungus, how can I bring these plants back to health?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The photo looks normal; the fronds that lay against the surface turn brown . They do not stay green like the regular fronds. I have a very large one, the only problem it ever had is scale insects .About the only way I know to kill them is scrape them off with a finger nail . So ,check for scale occasionally .

Comment: The antler fronds do look normal but the shield frond has a quickly growing brown spot that looks abnormal. I've had staghorn ferns for years and I've never seen the growing dark spot in the base like that. This is certainly different than when the shield front naturally gets older.